# Codeigniter chriskacerguis-RESTAPI Unknown access method

Tags: php, codeigniter, api

This is my Folder

```
Controller
  L>API
    L>ID
      L>Example.php
  L>Example.php
```

Both my example.php at API/example.php and API/ID/example.php were the same like this.

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
require APPPATH . '/core/REST_Controller.php';

/**
 * This is an example of a few basic user interaction methods you could use
 * all done with a hardcoded array
 *
 * @package         CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage      Rest Server
 * @category        Controller
 * @author          Phil Sturgeon, Chris Kacerguis
 * @license         MIT
 * @link            https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver
 */

class Example extends REST_Controller {
    public function index_get()
    {
        // index from a data store e.g. database
        $index = [
            ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'John', 'email' => 'john@example.com', 'fact' => 'Loves coding'],
            ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Jim', 'email' => 'jim@example.com', 'fact' => 'Developed on CodeIgniter'],
            ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Jane', 'email' => 'jane@example.com', 'fact' => 'Lives in the USA', ['hobbies' => ['guitar', 'cycling']]],
        ];

        $id = $this->get('id');
        $this->response($index, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }

    public function users_get(){
       echo"test";die();
    }
}
```

First I Adjust my config/routes.php like this

```
$route['API'] = "API";
$route['API/(.+)'] = "API/$1";
```

When I accessed base_url/API/Example/id/1 it responded the $index[1] that has name John.

Then I changed the routes.php into

```
$route["API/example"]="API/ID/example";
$route["API/example/(.+)"]="API/ID/example/(.+)";
```

Then I accessed I accessed base_url/API/Example/id/1
Which will go to API/ID/Example based on routes.php
But Its responded

```
{
"status": false
"message": "Unknown method"
}
```

But if I accesed base_url/API/Example?id=1
It responded with $index[1]

How can I call api from API/ID/Example.php using base_url/API/example/id/1
and it will return $index[1]? not status:false unknown method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the solution,
Its because my routing is wrong

```
$route['API/search_location/(.+)']="API/ID/example/index/$1";
$route['API/search_location']="API/ID/example";
```

Comment: search_location typo (it is API/example)